# tensorflow linker_flag in CROSSTOOL

Tags: tensorflow, installation, linker, bazel

I am working with Tensorflow 1.1.0 with gcc 5.2.0 and bazel 0.4.5
When I do:

```
    ./configure
    bazel build --verbose_failures --config=opt //tensorflow/tools/pip_package:build_pip_package
```

I got the following error messages:

```
ERROR: /remote/us03home4/rogerlo/.cache/bazel/_bazel_rogerlo/c6e718933b1d81ab029d890c5eecbc01/external/protobuf/BUILD:67
9:1: null failed: protoc failed: error executing command
  (cd /remote/us03home4/rogerlo/.cache/bazel/_bazel_rogerlo/c6e718933b1d81ab029d890c5eecbc01/execroot/tensorflow && \
  exec env - \
  bazel-out/host/bin/external/protobuf/protoc '--python_out=bazel-out/local-opt/genfiles/external/protobuf/python' -Iexternal/protobuf/python -Ibazel-out/local-opt/genfiles/external/protobuf/python bazel-out/local-opt/genfiles/external/protobuf/python/google/protobuf/any.proto bazel-out/local-opt/genfiles/external/protobuf/python/google/protobuf/api.proto bazel-out/local-opt/genfiles/external/protobuf/python/google/protobuf/compiler/plugin.proto bazel-out/local-opt/genfiles/external/protobuf/python/google/protobuf/descriptor.proto bazel-out/local-opt/genfiles/external/protobuf/python/google/protobuf/duration.proto bazel-out/local-opt/genfiles/external/protobuf/python/google/protobuf/empty.proto bazel-out/local-opt/genfiles/external/protobuf/python/google/protobuf/field_mask.proto bazel-out/local-opt/genfiles/external/protobuf/python/google/protobuf/source_context.proto bazel-out/local-opt/genfiles/external/protobuf/python/google/protobuf/struct.proto bazel-out/local-opt/genfiles/external/protobuf/python/google/protobuf/timestamp.proto bazel-out/local-opt/genfiles/external/protobuf/python/google/protobuf/type.proto bazel-out/local-opt/genfiles/external/protobuf/python/google/protobuf/wrappers.proto): com.google.devtools.build.lib.shell.BadExitStatusException: Process exited with status 1.
bazel-out/host/bin/external/protobuf/protoc: /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.20' not found (required by bazel-out/host/bin/external/protobuf/protoc)
bazel-out/host/bin/external/protobuf/protoc: /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `CXXABI_1.3.8' not found (required by bazel-out/host/bin/external/protobuf/protoc)
bazel-out/host/bin/external/protobuf/protoc: /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.18' not found (required by bazel-out/host/bin/external/protobuf/protoc)
bazel-out/host/bin/external/protobuf/protoc: /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.21' not found (required by bazel-out/host/bin/external/protobuf/protoc)
____Building complete.
Target //tensorflow/tools/pip_package:build_pip_package failed to build
____Elapsed time: 101.992s, Critical Path: 54.24s
make: *** [tensorflow] Error 1
```

But if I added this line:

```
    linker_flag: "-Wl,-rpath,/depot/gcc-5.2.0/lib64"
```

to the file

```
    $TENSORFLOW_ROOT/bazel-tensorflow/external/local_config_cc/CROSSTOOL
```

Build will pass.

I wonder if I can configure that linker_flag from the configure file or somewhere else?

I did add it to the build option but it doesn't work.

```
    bazel build --verbose_failures --config=opt --linkopt="-Wl,-rpath,/depot/gcc-5.2.0/lib6
4" //tensorflow/tools/pip_package:build_pip_package
```

**EDIT**: added bazel version

**SOLUTION**:

1. Add the linker option to the configuration of Bazel.
2. Recompile Bazel.
3. Compile Tensorflow with the recompiled Bazel will pass.

**Investigation**

The target is built by external crosstool, so the --linkopt won't work. According to the Bazel official [blog](https://blog.bazel.build/2016/03/31/autoconfiguration.html), the configuration of external crosstool (C++) is auto detected. It points to the [C++ configuration file](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/blob/9116b3e99af2fd31d92c9bb7c37905a1675456c1/tools/cpp/cc_configure.bzl#L161).

linker_flag rpath is computed by $LD_LIBRARY_PATH. That is, if you have some library paths defined in $LD_LIBRARY_PATH, Bazel will generate their rpath in the linker_flag.

But that dependency is removed because of [issue#2099](github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/issues/2099)

So setting $LD_LIBRARY_PATH doesn't work in [v0.4.5](github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/blob/0.4.5/tools/cpp/cc_configure.bzl#L250)

However, I haven't figure out how to do it correctly (setting env_action or something). So the quick solution is to hardcode it in the configuration file.

(Forgive me about the ugly hyperlinks above. My reputation is not enough to have more than 2 links in a post.)

Comment: Adding the flag as --linkopt doesn't work? It should (and it does in my little test case). Is the flag added to the linking command lines? You can inspect individual command lines Bazel emits using -s flag.

Comment: @mhlopko, no --linkopt doesn't work for me because the target is built by external crosstool. I will update my solution in the original post.

Answer (score 1):

[Copy my answer here]

**SOLUTION**:

1. Add the linker option to the configuration of Bazel.
2. Recompile Bazel.
3. Compile Tensorflow with the recompiled Bazel will pass.

**Investigation**

The target is built by external crosstool, so the --linkopt won't work. According to the Bazel official [blog](https://blog.bazel.build/2016/03/31/autoconfiguration.html), the configuration of external crosstool (C++) is auto detected. It points to the [C++ configuration file](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/blob/9116b3e99af2fd31d92c9bb7c37905a1675456c1/tools/cpp/cc_configure.bzl#L161).

linker_flag rpath is computed by $LD_LIBRARY_PATH. That is, if you have some library paths defined in $LD_LIBRARY_PATH, Bazel will generate their rpath in the linker_flag.

But that dependency is removed because of [issue#2099](github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/issues/2099)

So setting $LD_LIBRARY_PATH doesn't work in [v0.4.5](github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/blob/0.4.5/tools/cpp/cc_configure.bzl#L250)

However, I haven't figure out how to do it correctly (setting env_action or something). So the quick solution is to hardcode it in the configuration file.

(Forgive me about the ugly hyperlinks above. My reputation is not enough to have more than 2 links in a post.)

Comment: --linkopt should still work, even when the target is built by autogenerated crosstool. Can you reproduce? I'd be interested in what didn't work, as it is a possible bug in bazel. Thanks!

Comment: @mhlopko I will try to create a lightweight case to reproduce it. I wonder if Tensorflow somehow strip it off in one of the build rules. Though Bazel's manual says this always take precedence, is it possible to be overwritten?

Comment: It could, in theory, but tensorflow CROSSTOOL doesn't do that as far as I know.